# trying to run ./configure and ./make for ecos bintuils -

Tags: make, configure

I'm going from [Building a toolchain for use with eCos](http://ecos.sourceware.org/ecos/build-toolchain.html)
and I've got to the point where I'm configuring and building the tools for binutils:

```
./configure --target=arm-elf --prefix=../gnutools -v &> configure.out2
make -w all install &> make.out
```

but when I run the make, I get this error:

```
libtool: link: only absolute run-paths are allowed
```

It looks like libtool is trying to build the /bfd/libbfd.a library using an -rpath that doesn't exist:

```
libtool --mode=link gcc -W -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -g -O2  -o libopcodes.la -rpath ../gnutools/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/arm-elf/lib -release 2.13.1  dis-buf.lo disassemble.lo arm-dis.lo
```

so to get around that I set and env var LIBDIR to the lib directory I assume its looking for:

```
LIBDIR=/home/dan/dev/arm/crosstool/gcc-4.0.1-glibc-2.3.5/arm-linux/arm-linux/lib
```

and run a bash script which calls libtool with the above parameters except -rpath is set to $LIBDIR and it makes the libbfd.a library fine. Then I run make and it gets to trying to make the library for the opcodes directory and has the same problem. How to I set the -rpath in the configure script? Or even set it by editing the Makefile?

Comment: In your ./configure you've got `--prefix=../gnutools` and shouldn't it be `--prefix=/gnutools`? It wants a absolute path, not ..relative.

Comment: heynnema - that fixed it. I was doing my directories a little different than what the 'Building a toolchain..." page said. Now I'm having a different problem but I guess technically I have to start a new thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your ./configure you've got `--prefix=../gnutools` and it should be `--prefix=/gnutools`. It wants an absolute path, not ..relative.

Comment: `/gnutools` should target a folder at file system root, this doesn't make much sense

Comment: @Xerus What doesn't make much sense? /gnutools is at file system root. My answer did solve the problem for the OP.

Comment: I have never heard or seen such a folder at file system root.

Comment: @Xerus Correct. /gnutools normally doesn't exist... but without researching this old 2016 answer any further, I'd assume that the installer would create it. As I mentioned, my answer did solve the OP's question.

Comment: sure, I was merely curious. I have never seen a program that is not on OS/kernel-level create a new root folder.